# Shortest way to convert a Hash into String

Tags: ruby

there is a Hash like this:

```
params = { k1: :v1, k2: :v2, etc: :etc }
```

i need it converted to a string like this:

```
k1="v1", k2="v2", etc="etc"
```

i have a working version:

```
str = ""
params.each_pair { |k,v| str << "#{k}=\"#{v}\", " }
```

but it smells like ten PHP spirits ...

what's the Ruby way to do this?

Comment: Every object has to_s method in ruby.

Comment: yep, i know, but the output is quite different from what i need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
str = params.map {|p| '%s="%s"' % p }.join(', ')
```

see it in action [**here**](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=shortest-way-to-convert-a-hash-into-string.rb&run=true)

Comment: splendid, how does it work? i feel my mind is seriously screwed by long PHP years... :(  Djkastra was right - some languages does seriously damaging human minds

Comment: @oldergod, sorry? you simply call `params.map` in your code and it should work

Comment: @JamesEvans, you asking how does it work? simply. map block receives an array of key/val as first arg and we feed it to `%`, which is a shorthand for `printf`

Comment: I did not know it was a shorthand for `printf` and that is what I was asking for. Thanks, great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
hash.collect { |k,v| "#{k} = #{v}" }.join(" ,")
```

Comment: much better but i need value in double quotes

Comment: try this...hash.collect { |k,v| "#{k} = '#{v}' " }.join(" ,")...the compiler throws up backslashes when we try to change the order of double and single quotes...

Comment: hash.collect { |k,v| "#{k} = \"#{v}\"" }.join(" ,")...this is also an option but the o/p is "k1 = \"v1\" ,k2 = \"v2\" ,etc = \"etc\""